# Altair syntax for condition involving aggregate field

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to create a condition involving an aggregate field. For this example dataset

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['game1','player1',2,1],['game1','player2',3,4],['game1','player3',2,2]
                ,['game2','player1',0,3],['game2','player2',4,4],['game2','player3',3,3]]
                ,columns=['game','player','score1','score2']) 
color={'condition':[{"value":"green","test":"datum.score2 > datum.score1"}
                   ,{"value":"yellow","test":"datum.score2 == datum.score1"}
                   ,{"value":"red","test":"datum.score2 < datum.score1"}]}
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(x='score2',y='player',color=color)
```

I get this chart:

[image]

But if I wanted to have a chart displaying only the average for each player, I couldn't figure out a syntax that worked for the condition.

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(x='mean(score2)',y='player',color=color)
```

I tried:

```
"test":mean(datum.score2) > mean(datum.score1)"
```

and

```
"test":"datum.mean(score2) > datum.mean(score1)"
```

None of them worked. I couldn't find any syntax directions in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean()` is a shorthand in Altair that is available in encoding fields and transforms but not directly in conditions. To use the mean values in a condition, you need to create new columns for the mean values in a separate step via `transform_aggregate` (here we use [`transform_joinaggregate`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/joinaggregate.html) since you want to plot the original values in your dataframe and not the aggregated values):

```
color={
    'condition': [
        {"value":"green", "test": "datum.mean_score2 > datum.mean_score1"},
        {"value":"yellow", "test": "datum.mean_score2 == datum.mean_score1"},
        {"value":"red", "test": "datum.mean_score2 < datum.mean_score1"}
    ]
}

alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='score2',
    y='player',
    color=color
).transform_joinaggregate(
    mean_score1='mean(score1)',
    mean_score2='mean(score2)',
    groupby=['player']
)
```

[image]

If you want to plot the mean values, it would look like this:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='mean_score2:Q',
    y='player',
    color=color
).transform_aggregate(
    mean_score1='mean(score1)',
    mean_score2='mean(score2)',
    groupby=['player']
)
```

[image]

Comment: sorry I didn't make myself understood, I want to plot the mean values, so I will try transform aggregate

Comment: @flbyrne No worries, I added an example of plotting only the mean values in my answer above